# Is it useful to pass context to a function?

Tags: jsf

I usually do:

```java
public static void myUtilFunction(FacesContext context, [...]) {
    // TODO add code
}
```

instead of:

```java
public static void myUtilFunction([...]) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    // TODO add code
}
```

What is better?

Comment: OmniFaces [doesn't](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Components)

Comment: @JasperdeVries: excuse me, I don't know well Omnifaces, and I can't find in the code a function that gets the context :)

Comment: Mh. `FacesContext ` is not thread safe...

Comment: It's as being a threadlocal variable never intended to be thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overhead of getting the current `FacesContext` instance from the current thread is minimal. So I would choose to not add it as a parameter to utility methods to keep your code cleaner and more readable.

Also, if you look at [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org/) (the leading library when it comes to JSF utility functions), they don't require you to pass the `FacesContext`. For example:

```java
Messages.addGlobalInfo("Hello");
```

The library is maintained by BalusC (top JSF user on Stackoverflow), so I think you are good to go to follow his example.

Comment: I have to refactor a lot :D